# How to obtain page's organization in liferay portlet?

Tags: java, liferay, portlet

How to obtain page's organization in liferay portlet correctly?

I tried:

Company. Is not an organization, but a portal instance.

Group. Is group of current user, not of current page.

**UPDATE**

I am in the portlet class' `doView` method. I know how to pass anything I can obtain here upwards to JSP to be accessible via `EL/JSTL`.

**UPDATE 2**

`group.getOrganizationId()` always returns zero.

**UPDATE 3**

This code I use to prepare variables

```
private void storeVariables(RenderRequest renderRequest) {

    PortletPreferences prefs = renderRequest.getPreferences();
    String image_id = (String) prefs.getValue("image_id", "communicator");

    ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay)renderRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);

    Company company = themeDisplay.getCompany();

    Group group = themeDisplay.getScopeGroup();
    log.info("group = {}", group);

    long organizationId = group.getOrganizationId();
    log.info("organizationId = {}", organizationId);

    PortletDisplay portletDisplay = themeDisplay.getPortletDisplay();


    String contextPath = renderRequest.getContextPath();
    if( !contextPath.endsWith("/") ) {
        contextPath = contextPath + "/";
    }

    renderRequest.setAttribute("images", images);
    renderRequest.setAttribute("image", images.get(image_id));
    renderRequest.setAttribute("image_id", image_id);
    renderRequest.setAttribute("themeDisplay", themeDisplay);
    renderRequest.setAttribute("portletDisplay", portletDisplay);
    renderRequest.setAttribute("contextPath", contextPath);


}
```

**UPDATE 3**

The following code in JSP returns empty string

```
<!-- scopeGroupId = <c:out value="${scopeGroupId}"/> -->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *group* is a container of content and pages, and it's the internal entity for sites, layout scopes, staging and so on.

In Liferay 6.1, a *site* (which was called *community* in previous versions) can be associated to an organization. It depends on where you are (in a JSP, in the portlet class, etc.), but, if you have the entity representing the current Group, you can write something like this:

```
Organization organization = null;

if (group.isOrganization()) {
    organization = OrganizationLocalServiceUtil.getOrganization(group.getOrganizationId());
}
```

Hope it helps. Ask if you need help in order to retrieve the Group object...